# How to set a private field filled by constructor in test?

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, jasmine

I have a simple component which should preselect a value based on the current date:

```
export class VorgangComponent implements OnInit {
    private _date: Moment;

    constructor() {
        this._date = utc();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.preselectOption();
    }
```

No real rocket science.
I am wondering how to test this class. There are different ideas coming in my mind, but I don't know the recommended way:

- Date Service (seems for me like an overkill)
- protected member and use class inheritance for testing
- protected method and use class inheritance for testing

Did I miss anything? Is there any way to use jasmine for it?

Comment: You could fake time with for example [lolex](https://github.com/sinonjs/lolex) from sinonjs

Answer (score 1):

> Did I miss anything?

`private` and `public` don't exist in Javascript, it's only for compile time checking. During runtime, it's fully accessible. So you could just use the string acessor `component['_date']`. Only bad thing is you lose any intellisense and compile-time checking on the return value

Or you can just forget the `private` keyword. Style-wise, `_` already implies private (maybe not compile-wise). But even in the Angular source they don't use `private`. They just use `_`. It's a matter of style I guess. Not sure the reasoning behind why Angular chose this style, but personally it's something I just started to roll with also.